# Permission issues when trying to post to a page using Graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook, graph, permissions

I'm trying to post to facebook from my app as a page I manage. 
At time of authentication permission for `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` has been set.

Still when trying to post with the following code:

```
           FB.api(
                  "/"+pageId+"/feed",
                  "POST",
                  {
                      "message": "This is a test message #testing SDK"
                  },
                  function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    if (response && !response.error) {
                      console.log(response);
                    }
                  }
              );
```

It gives the following error message :

`(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action`

I tried checking the permission using

```
FB.api(
    "/me/permissions",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        console.log(response)
      }
    }
);
```

and confirmed that all required permission are granted.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you using a page access token?

Comment: I guess not , do i need to make the calls with access token ?

Comment: Where should i pass the access token ?

Comment: It is explained in the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api